ADODB Recordset always shows BOF and EOF even though Recordcount > 0
I am querying the Active Directory in VBScript as follows (I deleted the group path for confidential reasons):
set objCmd = createobject("ADODB.Command")   
set conn = createobject("ADODB.Connection")
Set iAdRootDSE = GetObject("LDAP://RootDSE")
strDefaultNamingContext = iAdRootDSE.Get("defaultNamingContext")
conn.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
conn.Open "Active Directory Provider"    
Set objCmd.ActiveConnection = conn 

strFilter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(memberof=" & ... & "))"    
strAttributes = "samaccountname,name,givenName,sn,displayName,streetAddress,postalCode,l,c,Homephone,TelephoneNumber,mail,userAccountControl"

strQuery = "<LDAP://" & strDefaultNamingContext & ">" & ";" & strFilter & ";" & strAttributes & ";subtree"

objCmd.CommandText = strQuery        
objCmd.Properties("Page Size") = 1000
objCmd.Properties("Timeout") = 30
objCmd.Properties("Cache Results") = False

Set colUsers = objCmd.Execute    

Msgbox "Start loop " & colUsers.RecordCount  & ", BOF: " & colUsers.BOF& ", EOF: " & colUsers.EOF 

The msgbox returns the following text: Start loop 42, BOF: True, EOF: True
So, I cannot loop through the recordset because EOF and BOF are true. Can you please help me why this happens and what I  can do?
Thank you!

What happens if you convert to an 2D Array using colUserArray = colUsers.GetRows() then use UBound(colUserArray, 2) to check the number of records? Here is an example that shows how to work with the 2D array - VBScript - Return a Recordset in an Array (SQL Like function).
